# How to cut an object using WebGL shaders?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, shader

I would like to cut an object (a box) in `WebGL` (`fragment shaders` / `vertex shaders`) without using Boolean operations (union, difference, etc..).

I want to use shaders to hide some part of the object (so it is therefore not really a "real cuts" since it simply hides the object).

**EDIT**

Comment: I have responded to your edit.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that the vertex shader passes through to the fragment shader the position in world space (or rather, whichever coordinate space you wish the clipping to be fixed relative to). Example (written from memory, not tested):

```
varying vec3 positionForClip;
...
void main(void) {
    ...
    vec4 worldPos = modelMatrix * vertexPosition;
    positionForClip = worldPos.xyz / worldPos.w;  // don't need homogeneous coordinates, so do the divide early
    gl_Position = viewMatrix * worldPos;
}
```

And in your fragment shader, you can then discard based on an arbitrary plane, or any other kind of test you want:

```
varying vec3 positionForClip;
uniform vec3 planeNormal;
uniform float planeDistance;
...
void main(void) {
    if (dot(positionForClip, planeNormal) > planeDistance) {
        // or if (positionForClip.x > 10.0), or whatever
        discard;
    }
    ...
    gl_FragColor = ...;
}
```

Note that using `discard` may cause a performance reduction as the GPU cannot optimize based on knowing that all fragments will be written.

Disclaimer: I haven't researched this myself, and only just wrote down a possible way to do it based on the 'obvious solution'. There may be better ways I haven't heard of.

---

Regarding your question about multiple objects: There are many different ways to handle this — it's all custom code in the end. But you certainly **can** use a different shader for different objects in your scene, as long as they're in different vertex arrays.

```
    gl.useProgram(programWhichCuts);
    gl.drawArrays();
    gl.useProgram(programWhichDoesNotCut);
    gl.drawArrays();
```

If you're new to using multiple programs, it's pretty much just like using one program except that you do all the setup (compile, attach, link) once. The main thing to watch out for is **each program has its own uniforms**, so you have to initialize your uniforms for each program separately.

Comment: Performance reduction is caused by discard or by the dotProduct check that is computed for every fragment although needed for part of them? Is setting opacity to 0 a more efficient way to achieve this or it's the same? (I'm relatively new to shader logic)

Comment: @konpsych Any shader containing a `discard` statement [may be ineligible for certain optimizations](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test). You cannot use transparency in blending instead for this “cutting” because the transparent areas will still be written to the depth buffer, possibly causing later geometry to not be drawn.

Comment: By looking at [this project](http://open-3d-viewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/web/index.html) the transparency seems to work well and I am pretty sure it uses shaders and specifically the first function [here](https://code.google.com/p/open-3d-viewer/source/browse/trunk/web/scripts/shaders.txt)

Comment: I just noticed you work for google so you might know better about this project but what I figured out is that the layers with higher opacity are drawn first and that is probably sufficient to avoid errors, given the structure

Comment: @konpsych WebGL draws primitives in the order they are presented in the buffer. If there is any such sorting going on, it must be happening in the application; that makes it possible to get consistent results from transparent surfaces.